# vscode intellisense to show types for all suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code

Current behavior: vscode intellisense only shows type for currently selected item.

[image: current]

Goal: see helpful types for all suggestions, like in Atom.

[image: desired]

I am comfortable with writing extension or modifying vscode source and using fork. Just please point in the right direction.

```
Version: 1.41.1
Commit: 26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0
Date: 2019-12-18T14:57:51.166Z
Electron: 6.1.5
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 17.7.0
```

Comment: Looking for this as well. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can build vscode, this crude patch [temoto@vscode 2f0a502](https://github.com/temoto/vscode/commit/2f0a502e756ab22eecd848b9ae204e9ccd9f41c4) fixes the issue. Basically, treat all suggest rows same, no matter which one is focused.

Downside: [duplicated info in entry and details block](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87882#issuecomment-569713409) which doesn't bother me, but needs to be fixed for clean solution.

I'm having (irrelevant here) vscode build issues, so just modified file `app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.css`

Official route with feature request [vscode#87882](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87882) went constructive at first, closed as duplicate (by mistake?) of nothing later. I can relate to someone being upset about good intention feature treated like unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is by-design VS Code 1.41 and cannot be controlled/changed by an extension

Please file a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?template=feature_request.md) against VS Code if you would like this changed

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I created [vscode#87882](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87882) and after constructive discussion it was closed as duplicate, I think by mistake because there is no similar issue.